# Prevent bad data being selected with SQL Server COLLATE

Tags: sql-server

I have two databases and I am moving data from one database another. On some columns I need to resolve a collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI". So I currently do:

```
SELECT [column] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
        FROM    xxx
```

This works in the main but in some fields I see characters like:

```
&#65533;
```

In the data that has been copied across. It seems some characters from the original DB are lost when the collation is changed on the new DB. Now I know I can use REPLACE to get rid of them, but I wondered rather than search the entire record set - is there a way to filter out or prevent the special characters coming across in the first place?

Comment: I imagine it will work if you declare your columns as nvarchar instead of varchar

Comment: I am already using nvarchar(80) I'm afraid!